# Ionic error page for invalid segments

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I don't like that I can go to http://localhost:8100/#/asdfasd and get the normal start page.  I want that to be an error page.

I tried to implement this by creating a `NoSuchPageComponent` and setting `rootPage` to that in the `AppComponent`.  (I also made `NoSuchPageComponent#ionViewDidEnter` navigate to the home page when no segment is present.)

This works when the browser navigates to http://localhost:8100/#/asdfasd, but if I first open any real page and then change the address bar to http://localhost:8100/#/asdfasd, I get the Ionic error handler showing "Uncaught (in promise): invalid views to insert"

1. Is there another way this is expected to be done?
2. Is there somewhere I can catch that error?
3. Does this have anything to do with lazy loading?

**How can I make this work as I intend?**

Here's the full error message:

```
Runtime Error
Uncaught (in promise): invalid views to insert
Stack
Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid views to insert
    at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:18260)
    at Object.reject (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:17682)
    at NavControllerBase._fireError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:46029:16)
    at NavControllerBase._failed (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:46017:14)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:46072:59
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:13979)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4248:33)
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:13919)
    at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9146)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:18750
Ionic Framework: 3.7.0
Ionic App Scripts: 3.0.1
Angular Core: 4.4.3
Angular Compiler CLI: 4.4.3
Node: 6.12.0
OS Platform: macOS Sierra
Navigator Platform: MacIntel
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.89 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: I'm facing the exact problem. The problem is only when navigating by URL (link or typing in the address bar).

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I've got the same issue :(

Comment: No, but I haven't worked with Ionic since July 2018, so I wouldn't know about any newer developments.